# ng changes does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a dropdown like  below

```
<select class="form-control"
                                            data-ng-model="vm.priceBuilder.projectID"
                                            data-ng-change="vm.changeProject(option)"
                                            data-ng-options="option.pK_ProjectID as option.projectNumber for option in vm.projectList">
                                        <option value="">Please select...</option>
                                    </select>
```

and my controller binding is

```
changeProject(selectedProject) {
            this.getSubTask(selectedProject.fK_ProjectID);
        };
```

Here selectedProject is undefined. what is actual cause I can not understand.

Answer (score 0):

clearly `option` is not defined you need to call the ng-change wither with the model or use the model in your function.

```
<select class="form-control"
                                        data-ng-model="vm.priceBuilder.projectID"
                                        data-ng-change="vm.changeProject(vm.priceBuilder.projectID)"
                                        data-ng-options="option.pK_ProjectID as option.projectNumber for option in vm.projectList">
                                    <option value="">Please select...</option>
                                </select>
```